# Just for fun, how do I write a ruby program that slowly prints to stdout one character at a time?

Tags: ruby, stdout

I thought this might work

```
 "a b c d e f g h i j k".each {|c| putc c ; sleep 0.25}
```

I expected to see "a b c d e f j" be printed one character at a time with 0.25 seconds between each character. But instead the entire string is printed at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need to use `.each_char` to iterate over the characters.  In Ruby 1.8, `String.each` will go line-by-line.  In Ruby 1.9, `String.each` is deprecated.
2. You should manually flush `$stdout` if you want the chars to appear immediately.  Otherwise, they tend to get buffered so that the characters appear all at once at the end.

.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
"a b c d d e f g h i j k".each_char {|c| putc c ; sleep 0.25; $stdout.flush }
```

Answer (score 5):

Two things:

1. You need to split that string into an array before you use `each` on it.
2. Turn off [output buffering](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000910).

   ```
   $stdout.sync = true
   "a b c d d e f g h i j k".split(" ").each {|c| putc c ; sleep 0.25}
   ```

Comment: you don't need the parameter to split(), as that is the default. `.split.each` will do.

Comment: @Mark, That's cool!  I don't really know Ruby, I just answered "for fun" but I was one minute faster than erjiang :D

Answer (score 2):

Ruby buffers output and will flush it to standard output after it reaches a certain size. You can force it to flush like so.

```
"a b c d e f g h i j k".each_char do |char|
   putc char
   $stdout.flush
   sleep 0.25
end
```

Note: if you don't want spaces between the characters when printed, use `.split.each` instead of `.each_char`.

**Just for fun**: with a definition like this:

```
def slowly
  yield.each_char { |c| putc c; $stdout.flush; sleep 0.25 }
end
```

You would be able to do this:

```
slowly do
  "a b c d e f g h i j k"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
%w"a b c d e f g h i j k".each {|c| putc c ; sleep 0.25}
```

That works as is with Ruby 1.9.2, which doesn't need STDOUT to flush between each write.

If you want the intervening spaces remove `%w` and use `each_char` instead of `each`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my way of "slow printing":

```
for i in "a b c d e f g h i j k".chars.to_a
  print i
  sleep 0.25
end
```